# Wrapping multiple words with HTML tags using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using RegExp to make some quick replacements in a potentially large set of text.  What it's doing is providing a means for syntax highlighting:

```
var text = 'throw new Error("foo");';
text = text.replace(/(^|\W)(throw|new|Error)(\W|$)/g,'$1<span class="syntax-reserved-word">$2</span>$3');
```

Problem is, it highlights "throw" and "Error" but skips right over "new".  My RegExp specifies beginning of string or non-word, then throw or new or Error, non-word or end of string.  So after it finds "^throw ", wouldn't the search position begin at the n in "new", meaning it should match "^new "?

Comment: There are plenty of [JS syntax highlighters](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/) freely available. Are you sure you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Yes, this is for my personal API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\b` (word boundary) instead of a non-word-char:

```
text = text.replace(/\b(throw|new|Error)\b/g,'<span class="syntax-reserved-word">$1</span>');
```

Comment: Bah.. why didn't I think of this!?  Works as expected, thanks!